# ¿Porque cuando uso el SSR el codigo se ejecuta dos veces?

Tags: vue3, nuxt

Hola estoy tratando de implementar una pagina con SSR en nuxt 3 para tratar de entender mejor esta tecnologia.  y me estoy dando cuenta que cuando coloco un `console.log()` en un componente despliega un mensaje en la consola del servidor y luego lo muestra nuevamente en el navegador.

Esto no significaria que mis script se ejecutaran dos veces cada vez que se inicie mi pagina?

Eso me hace dudar de como deberian implementarse los scripts para que realmente se proporcione una carga inicial mas rápida. Agradezco si pueden darme una explicación o guia para hacer un buen eso del SSR.

app.vue

```
 <template>
        <div id="app">
            <MenuFixed />
            <NuxtPage></NuxtPage>
        </div>
 </template>
 <script setup>
    console.log(`este texto se muestra en el servidor y el cliente`)
 </script>
```

Comment: Sin un [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), es díficil que otros puedan validar tu escenario.

Comment: agregado el ejemplo.

Comment: está bastante complicado entender el problema, tienes algún repositorio público donde se pueda ver el código? ya que quizás el problema no se encuentre en el snippet que acabas de compartir, podría estar en algún componente padre, hijo o en la configuración de nuxt.